# System malloc vs DLMalloc on large malloc

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

I haven't coded in a while, so excuse me upfront. I have this odd problem. I am trying to malloc 8GB in one go and I plan to manage that heap with TLSF later on. That is, I want to avoid mallocing throughout my application at all, just get one big glob at the beginning and freeing it in the end. Here is the peculiarity though. I was always using dlmalloc until now in my programs. Linking it in and everything went well. However, now when I try to malloc 8GB at once and link in dlmalloc to use it I get segmentation fault 11 on OSX when I run it, without dlmalloc everything goes well. Doesn't matter if I use either gcc or clang. System doesn't have 8GB of RAM though, but it has 4GB. Interestingly enough same thing happens on Windows machine which has 32GB of RAM and Ubuntu one that has 16GB of RAM. With system malloc it all works, allocation goes through and simple iteration through allocated memory works as expected on all three systems. But, when I link in dlmalloc it fails. Tried it both with malloc and dlmalloc function calls.

Allocation itself is nothing extraordinary, plain c99.

```
[...]
size_t bytes = 1024LL*1024LL*1024LL*8LL;
unsigned long *m = (unsigned long*)malloc(bytes);
[...]
```

I'm confused by several things here. How come system malloc gives me 8GB malloc even without system having 4GB or RAM, are those virtual pages? Why dlmalloc doesn't do the same? I am aware there might not be a continuos block of 8GB of RAM to allocate, but why segmentation fault then, why not a null ptr?

Is there a viable robust (hopefully platform neutral) solution to get that amount of RAM in one go from malloc even if I'm not sure system will have that much RAM?

edit: program is 64-bit as are OS' which I'm running on.

edit2: 
So I played with it some more. Turns out if I break down allocation into 1GB chunks, that is 8 separate mallocs, then it works with dlmalloc. So it seems to be an issue with contiguous range allocation where dlmalloc probably tries to allocate only if there is a contiguous block. This makes my question then even harder to formulate. Is there a somewhat sure way to get that size of a memory chunk with or without dlmalloc across platforms, and not have it fail if there is no physical memory left (can be in swap, as long as it doesn't fail). Also would it be possible in a cross platform manner to tell if malloc is in ram or swap.

Comment: How big is the swap partition for the system you are using?

Comment: 100GB on OSX, 600GB dedicated just for that purpose on other two systems (windows and other linux machine).

Comment: Not sure about the difference between DLmalloc and malloc, but the reason you are able to malloc 8 GB is exactly the reason you said, they are virtual pages.  When a machine doesn't have enough physical RAM to support the RAM necessary it will use hard disk space.  Functionally it works but it is significantly slower to read/write to

Answer (score 2):

I will give you just a bit of perspective, if not an outright answer.  When I see you attempting to allocate 8GB of contiguous RAM, I cringe.  Yes, with 64-bit computing and all, that is probably "legal", but on a normal machine, you are probably going to run into a lot of edge cases, 32-bit legacy code choking on a 64-bit size, and just plain usability issues getting a chunk of memory big enough to make this work.  If you want to try this sort of thing, perhaps attempt to `malloc` the single chunk, then if that fails, use smaller chunks.  This somewhat defeats the purpose of a 1 chunk system though.  Perhaps there is some sort of "page size" in the OS that you could link your malloc size to - in order to help performance and just plain ability to get memory in the amount you wish.

On game consoles, this approach to memory management is somewhat common - allocate 1 buffer from the OS at bootup as big as possible, then place your own memory manager on there to avoid OS overhead and possible inferior allocation code.  It also allows one to better control memory fragmentation on such systems where virtual memory doesn't exist.  But on these systems, you also know up front exactly how much RAM you have.

Is there a way to see if memory is physical or virtual in a platform independent way?  I don't think so, but perhaps someone else can give a good answer to that and I'll edit this part away.

So not a 100% answer, but some random thoughts to help out and my internally wondering what you are doing that wants 8GB of RAM in one chunk when it sounds like multiple chunks will work fine. :)

Comment: First to answer your question. I tried the lazy approach of getting a large chunk of memory so I can load a bunch of large exr images into it for faster access and moving through them. I don't think it's that wild of an idea. :) That's my main motivation here. Other, you have described it. Down the road I'd like to make a game and I'd like to do it the way it's done on consoles, but apparently it's not going to work like that. Seems like I'll have to have two separate memory managements. One for consoles with one big chunk and other consisting of multiple ones.Is there an existing solution?

Comment: Not really.  Cross developed titles usually have a common high level memory interface, but under the hood, each has native code that takes advantage of that systems quirks.  8GB though.  That is so much space!  What are you doing and where are you planning to port that takes that kind of footprint?  Perhaps XBone or PS4 work - those both have 8GB, but I am going to guess that OS and overhead will eat quite a bit of that.  The Wii U has around 1GB usable if I recall, the next current generation console and anything older will be much smaller.

Comment: BTW, if this is just for optimization, that large of a file will probably span multiple virtual pages and my guess is that could eat any performance you may gain by using a single buffer.  Just allocate the size you need and free it.  That is what consoles do - though the order of allocation and freeing is watched carefully to prevent fragmentation.

Comment: I already performed a test (on smaller amount of RAM). I get a significant boost in performance while keeping all of it in RAM no matter the access pattern since files are large and it's an IO bound bottleneck problem. Can you elaborate more on console way of things, is it appropriate on desktop too? Maybe some kind of resources you can point me to? Thanks!